# why requirejs can not load any in my example?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I write a simple test using RequireJS, here is my main.js

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "/resource/js",
    paths: {
        jquery: "lib/jquery-2.0.3",
        'jquery.validate': "lib/jquery.validate",
        bootstrap: "lib/bootstrap",
        back: "lib/back.js"
    }
});
```

and index.html to print a simple information to the console：

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@include file="lib/lib.jsp"%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resource/js/require.js" defer async="true" data-main="/resource/js/main"/>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>fagkadgkkgjkd</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  的SD敢达法规范和风格和
  fsfsdgdgfdg
  <script type="text/javascript">
      console.log("in this js");
      require(['jquery'],function($){
          console.log($);
          console.log("execute here");
      });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

what happened is require.js and main.js is loaded properly, but jquery.js is never loaded and this jsp file print nothing to the brower.  The structure of the static file is as following:

```
/resource
----js
    ---lib
        jquery.js
        bootstrap.js
    require.js
    main.js
----css
----img
```

so, my question is how can I change the code to make this jsp work right？

Comment: I assume you get an error like "undefined is not a function" ?

Comment: If you turn on Network debugging in your browser, can you see if/where it's sending a request for JQuery? Your method seems correct, but something might cause it to look in the wrong place.

Comment: main.js and requirejs is loaded properly, but there is none request send for jquery.

Comment: plus, the request url for jquery `http://localhost:8080/resource/js/lib/jquery-2.0.3.js` can get jquery.